# Notation for inductive definitions of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Is there a formal notation for *inductive definitions* of sets?
For example, like this:

$Closure(U,C,A)$

where $U$ is a set, $C$ is a set of *constructors* (in a simple case, operations on the set $U$), $A$ is a subset of $U$.

$Closure(U,C,A)$ denotes the minimal subset of U, containing the set $A$ and closed under the operations from the set $C$.

Comment: The best I can think of is the Skolem hull of $A$ in the appropriate structure.

Comment: Yes. I know what is a Skolem hull. And if your language includes all the operations in $C$, then this is just that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any such notation in general use (and I have read a lot of theoretical computer science papers where it would have been handy to have one).

Computer-assisted or -verified proof systems often need an easy way to express this sort of definitions, but none of their choices seem to have spread into general mathematical prose.

The closest we get is the "free" case where the ranges of the operators in $C$ are all disjoint from each other and from $A$ (and $U$ can be left implicit), in which case (at least) computer scientists will tend to use *abstract grammars* to define the set.

Comment: Would you have a link to the documentation of such a definition in one of these computerized proof systems?

Comment: @DanChristensen: No, not really. I believe I've seen them popping up on slides when people talk about their work with such systems, is all.

Comment: @DanChristensen: I would like to have such a link.